# settings.gradleから依存関係を持つjarファイルを作成する方法

Tags: java, gradle, jar

[英語のStack Overflowに質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74589405/create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies-from-settings-gradle)しても回答がつかなかったのでこちらでも質問します。
現在のGradleはbuild.gradleだけでなくsettings.gradleも作るようになっていて依存関係などもそこに書くようになっているのでjarファイルを作るにはそれを使う必要があると思いますが、検索してもbuild.gradleからjarファイルを作る方法しか出てきません。
settings.gradleから依存関係を持つjarファイルを作成するにはどうすればいいでしょう？

追記：
自分が見たページは https://qiita.com/yoshiyu0922/items/4662a3d5f4eb29880a65 や https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871656/using-gradle-to-build-a-jar-with-dependencies ですが、情報が古いせいかjarファイルができなかったりエラーが起きたりしました。
[Gradle Shadow Plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/introduction/#benefits-of-shadow)を使う方法だとできそうなのですが、

```
> shadow.org.apache.tools.zip.Zip64RequiredException: archive contains more than 65535 entries.

  To build this archive, please enable the zip64 extension.
  See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip:zip64
```

というエラーが出て、エラーメッセージなどを参考に

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "trend_detect.TrendAnalyzerBoot"
    }
    zip64 = true
}
```

とbuild.jarに書きましたがまだエラーが出ます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

残念ながら、現在の質問文から質問者の置かれている状況ややりたいことを類推することは難しいです。
もう少し具体的な説明が必要です。

想像で補完して回答すると、

> 検索してもbuild.gradleからjarファイルを作る方法しか出てきません。

この方法が具体的にどういうものかわかりませんが、同じ方法で実現できると思われます(大抵の場合は `./gradlew build` コマンドではないかと思われます)。

また、 `settings.gradle` が置かれているディレクトリで

```
./gradlew tasks
```

コマンドを実行すれば実行可能なタスク一覧が取得できますので、それを見れば判明することもあるかもしれません。

---

[こちらの質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74589405/4506703)からは、 fat-jar を作成したいのかな、とも思われました。

その場合も、single module project と設定方法は同様です。
例えば[Gradle Shadow Plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/introduction/)を利用するのであれば、mainクラスを含むモジュールにこれをセットアップするだけです。
([プロジェクトサンプル](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/main/jaso92559))

Comment: このGradle Shadow Pluginを使う方法だと確かにできそうなのですがまだ問題があります。長くなったので質問文への追記を見ていただきたいです。

Comment: @lamrongol [このissueへのコメント](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/107#issuecomment-66461675) によると、 `zip64` の設定は (`jar` task ではなく) `shadowJar` task に対して行うべきのように見えます。

Comment: 試したところjarを作成でき、実行もできたのですがプログラムが途中で止まってしまいました。エラーメッセージが表示されないのかわかりませんが原因はわかりません。

Comment: 調べたところ普通に動かした場合もプログラムが止まることがあるのでGradle Shadow Pluginによるビルド自体は正常に動作するようです。